# Importing Data Into SQL From Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have report writing software where we can get data from our system and dump it to an Excel file. I have a report that runs daily and then I have a job in SQL that imports that data to a table in one of our databases. The issue I'm running into is if there is no data in the report for that day, the report just says 'No Data Available' and it doesn't import anything or clear out the table so the data from the previous day is still in the table. Is there a way I can get it to clear the table each time whether there is data in that Excel file or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the data from previous days reports why not just throw:

DELETE FROM [Name of table]

At it before you start your import

Comment: So I have a scheduled job that runs a SSIS package, which is the only step in the job. Could I add the DELETE FROM command to the scheduled job and just have it be the first step and the SSIS package be the next step?

Comment: I was going to ask if you were using SSIS which sounds sensible. I would say yes but test it somewhere safe first :)